# Parameterization of boundary curve in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am considering a function of the form:

u0 = p[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)]*(Q1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)] - K1)/(p[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)] - K1 + Sqrt[(K1)^2 - m1^2]*(1 - 2*alpha));

with p[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)],Q1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)], and m1 being constant (set p[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)] = 1, Q1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qumLG.png)] = 1/2, m1 = 0.1). Therefore, i am considering u0 as a function of K1 and alpha. Due to physical restrictions, i want my u0 to be between the values 4/9 and 0.48, while K1 might be between 0.1 and 1/2 and alpha between 1/2 and 1. One can easily check that the domain for K1 and alpha are too large in order to guarantee that u0 lies between 4/9 and 0.48 by checking the equation above. Hence, i need to restrict alpha or K10 such that u0 always lies in my desired domain. A plot might be somewhat revealing:

Plot3D[u0Max3*0.48, {K1, 0.1, 1/2}, {alpha, 1/2, 1}, PlotRange -> {4/9, 0.48}];
[image]

Ultimately, i aim for integrating this volume with numerical procedures like NIntegrate or Vegas, but for this i need to state the domain of the variables. So i am looking for a way to get a functional dependence between alpha and K1 such that i can integrate this and obtain the correct volume.

Comment: You can use `Boole` or `Ramp` to avoid explicit specification of the variable domains. For example, let `u[x_,y_]:=Sin[x^2 + y^3];`, then you can use 
`NIntegrate[ Ramp[u[x,y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`  or
`NIntegrate[Boole[u[x,y]>0]u[x,y],{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but using this type of functions nevertheless leads to a larger volume than the one which is actually required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function defined:

```
p1 = 1;
Q1 = 1/2;
m1 = 1/10;
u0[K1_, alpha_] := p1 (Q1 - K1)/(p1 - K1 + Sqrt[K1^2 - m1^2] (1 - 2 alpha))
```

writing:

```
restrictions = {4/9 < u0[K1, alpha] < 48/100, 1/10 < K1 < 1/2, 1/2 < alpha < 1};
domain = ImplicitRegion[restrictions, {K1, alpha}];
NIntegrate[u0[K1, alpha] - 4/9, {K1, alpha} ∈ domain]
```

we get:

> 0.000517558

which should correspond to the requested volume.

In a less cryptic way, writing:

```
Reduce[restrictions]
```

we get:

> 1/2 < alpha < 1 && 1/10 < K1 < (-41 + 64 alpha - 64 alpha^2)/(-90 - 640 alpha + 640 alpha^2)

then writing:

```
NIntegrate[u0[K1, alpha] - 4/9, {alpha, 1/2, 1}, {K1, 1/10, (-41 + 64 alpha - 64 alpha^2)/(-90 - 640 alpha + 640 alpha^2)}]
```

we get:

> 0.000517558

which of course is identical to the previous one.